# Ice pack/cold piece of metal contoured to skull/forehead

Tags: fever, cold-compress, forehead, temples, frozen-freeze

There are ice packs people put on their forehead when they get hit on the head or have a fever.

I thought- perhaps I could have the ice pack molded to the shape of my skull/forehead. It would cover alot more surface area. Also trying to find something that pinches/clamps gently to my temples which seem to get warm the fastest that can cool my temples off.

There are things like elastogel which does this sort of but are not nearly as cold as an ice pack or a piece of metal that has been in the freezer for a day.

What would I need to do to make this happen? Some kind of product or DIY?

Perhaps not an icepack but a few centimeter thick piece of metal that will be very cold when you put it in the freezer for a while.